# how to create pdf from network images in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am developing an app in which the images coming from a website. So, I have to make PDF file from multiple pictures to print it or share the PDF file through email. I can make this pdf file by images from local assets but not from network images.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the network images first and then making a PDF from them

Comment: thank you, that is a very good approach. is there any alternative way to make pdf from network images without downloading them ? @zinbrox